# Print labels for rows and columns in grid (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arrays, grid, rows, label

I apologize if this question has been posted before, however if it was, I was not able to find it anywhere. Also, I am not familiar with numpy. Unfortunately the only answers I could find were numpy aswers. I would prefer not to use numpy as I am still learning the basics of coding/python.

I am trying to print out labels for my grid. I have a simple game board, and I would like to label the columns A,B,C,D and the rows 1,2,3,4.

Here is my code that generates the grid:

> ```
> def initial(): #Function that creates the 2d array and assigns it the values I want
> board = []
> for x in range(numrows):
>     board.append([])
>     for y in range(numcols):   
>         if ((x + y)%2):        
>            board[x].append('X')   
>         else:
>             board[x].append('O')
> ```

Here is the output:

> ```
>   O X O X
>   X O X O
>   O X O X
> ```

I am trying to make my output look like this:

> ```
>     A  B  C  D 
> 1   O  X  O  X
> 2   X  O  X  O
> 3   O  X  O  X
> ```

I know that I have to manipulate the indexes, not the values, but like I said, I'm still a noob. What would be the best way to go about this based on what I have here? Should it be separate for loops and print statements than the code that makes the initial grid? Or can I somehow alter my initial game board code to implement these row/column labels?

So far, I have the idea of doing something like this:

> ```
>       for r in range(numrows): # I have a variable in the code numrows = 3
>         if(r==0):
>             print("1")
>         if(r==1):
>             print("2")
>         if(r==2):
>             print("3")
>         for c in range(numcols): # also a variable numcols = 4
>             if(c==0):
>                 print("A")
>             if(c==1):
>                 print("B")
>             if(c==2):
>                 print("C")
>             if(c==3):
>                 print("D")
>         show_grid(board) #function that prints my board
> ```

I think I am close, however am at my wits end.. I need help. Thanks in advance for the time and effort taken to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something modular (hence Pythonic :p):

```
columnsIndices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
rowsIndices = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(" ", end="")
for c in columnsIndices :
    print(" " + str(c), end="")      #str() is useless, but it's good practice
print()                              #linefeed
for i in range(len(grid)) :
    print(str(rowsIndices[i]), end="")
    for elt in grid[i] :
        print(" " + str(elt), end="")
    print()                          #linefeed
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Helped a ton!!